# redux devtools chrome extensions - No store found

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, redux

I'm trying to setup my chrome extension project which uses React and Redux. I believe i've successfully setup redux as i'm managing to get some console logs form store updates but i'm having difficulty getting the redux dev tools to work. Currently when I inspect element on my extension popup and go to the redux tab I get a "No store found" message. I think i've followed the documentation for the [extension](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension)

just fine so i'm not exactly sure why I would be getting this message. Here is my store.js file:

```
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import testReducer from './reducers/testReducer'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';

// create store with reducer, inital state and activating redux devtools
const store = createStore(testReducer,0,
       composeWithDevTools
                         )

store.subscribe(() => {
    console.log("store changed",store.getState())
})

export default store;
```

I also tried replacing the `composeWithDevTools` line with `window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()` after searching for a solution online but still no joy. Can anyone spot where i've gone wrong?

Comment: i seem to recall having to call the init function for devtools in my entrypoint js file (index.js) as well as attaching it to the window object... Maybe try instantiating it outside of the store. Just a thought.

Comment: I just tried attaching it to the window object and calling it with composeWithDevTools in index.js but still doesn't work. When I type window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ in the console I get an undefined message. Not sure if this could be relevant to the issue?

Comment: You may check the sample code in this [thread](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/issues/126#issuecomment-222605604). Be noted that you should import `compose` from `redux`. Also, maybe you are using an older version of Redux. Passing enhancer as the 3rd parameter is supported only for redux@>=3.1.0. For older versions, check this [link](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/blob/v0.4.2/examples/counter/store/configureStore.js#L7-L12).

Comment: This video explains how to connect redux devtool to basic react redux app - https://youtu.be/TSOVLXQPWgA

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have made a syntax error.
// this is the correct syntax

```
const store = createStore(testReducer,0,composeWithDevTools())
```

write `composeWithDevTools()` instead of `composeWithDevTools`.